# Compare 2 hours on vba Excel before and after midnight

Tags: excel, vba

Im using **vba in Excel 2007**

To simplify, I have 3 cells with hours.

```
Cell1 = 18:00

Cell2 = 01:00 ' (next day) (The user enters only the time)

Cell3 = 23:00
```

And when comparing them

```
If (Cell3 >= Cell1 And Cell3 < Cell2) Then

End If
```

The If condition results in `false`, because excel doesn't know that is the next day.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are your cells set As Date ? Does your cells only contain 01:00 for example ? else you will not be able to do wha you need, yuo need to set your cells as date and format those cells in order to display the hour only

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: The cells are formated in 'hh:mm'.


It takes a long time to put the dates and we are only interested in the hours, but after midnight is where the problem appears

Comment: Yeah xD the question is:
Some way that the user entering only the hours example  00:30 And when comparing with another previous hour example 23:00 can say that it is less since 00:30 is the next day.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention you @Dorian

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention you @CLR

Comment: @Stack Is the `If` Statement used to check date chronology ?

Comment: @Dorian Any help is welcome

Comment: @Dorian Yes, is used for that, 
The user enters only the hours because each day is filled in, and it has to be something that simple, I can not tell the user to fill in the date also xD, but of course 00:00 is already the next day and the smallest of all hours

Comment: @Stack Do you have at least a  1st date somewhere ? So i can increment this date

Answer (score 0):

If Cell1 is in `D1` and Cell2 is `E1` and times are in chronological order then something like this should work:

```
=SUM(TODAY(),IF(E1<D1,1,0),E1)-SUM(TODAY(),D1)
```

It adds the date to the time (what date doesn't matter as you're only after the time difference).  Todays date is added to the time in D1, if the time in E1 is less than the time in D1 it uses tomorrows date and then subtracts the two date/times to get your result.

Hope that made sense. :)